# Is it possible to model seasonal time series with limited set of data

Tags: time-series, model-selection, seasonality

Suppose we have a set of data only for week. And we can clearly see that a weekend influences data. Is it possible and would it be right to model and forecast data for next week.

Comment: Your setup is weird. So you can't wait a few weeks to collect more data?

Comment: I can collect more data, but I ask the question to better understand the topic.

Answer (score 0):

if you only had data for 1 week ... you could use the 5 non-weekend average as the expectation for the non-weekend days and use the observed sat as the prediction for next sat and likewise for sun. A refinement might be to test to see of the 5 non-weekend values are free of outliers/pulses. I one or more pulses is detected then simply use the average of the other npn-weekend days (free of anomalies)